# Echo off in bat file isn't working

Tags: batch-file, echo

So I wrote a short bat file which creates user and some more:

```
@echo off
net user egzamin /add
net user egzaming /expires:17/07/17
net user egzamin /logonpasswordchg:YES
pause
exit
```

what I get from it is:
C:\Users\Ja\Desktop>´╗┐@echo /off
'´╗┐@echo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Rest works just fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://superuser.com/q/769601/608614

Answer (score 2):

Your editor saved the file with a `BOM` = [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). You can check this viewing the file with a hex viewer.

```
> hex.exe Test.txt
HEX:       +00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07  08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f  0123456789abcdef
0000000000: EF BB BF 40 45 63 68 6F  20 6F 66 66              ´╗┐@Echo off
```

To avoid this take care when saving and select the proper encoding and no BOM.

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper text editor to edit batch files. Editplus is my preference - others use notepad++ and other utilities.

Note pad is barely adequate, and like word-processors, attempts to format the text to "make sense".

You need to save your file as ASCII - you appear to have some extraneous characters before the `@`

Answer (score 0):

Save the .Bat file as:

```
UTF8 without BOM
```